# When updating password I am getting error in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to update a user password, but I am getting an error.

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax;  'where `name` is null' at line 1 (SQL: update `users` set 
>   where `name` is null)

**Controller**

```php
public function passwordupdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->save();

    return response()->json([
        'msg' => 'Password has been Updated',
    ]);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('teachers/policy', 'UsersController@passwordupdate')
```

From the view, I am sending the user id and name to the controller through an Ajax request.

**Ajax**

```js
$('.update-password').on('click', function (e) {
    let user_id = $('#update-password').val();
    console.log('Update password clicked!')
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: "/users/" + $('#update-password').attr("value"),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.msg) {
                $('#response').empty();
                $(".toast").toast('show');
                $('#response').append(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**View**

```php
<form id="password-form">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-nowrap">
                <select name="name" id="username" class="form-control border border-secondary border-dark" required>
                    <option selected value="">SELECT USER</option>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <option value="{{ $user->name }}"> {{ $user->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">
                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Type Password"
                       class="form-control border border-secondary border-dark">
            </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm update-password rounded text-center"
                        value="{{ $user->id }}" id="update-password">
                    <span class="fa fa-key"> </span> UPDATE PASSWORD
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: yes it's correct

Comment: show User model

Comment: Your route is POST on `/teachers/policy` but your request is sent as a POST to `/users/{id}`

Comment: @apokryfos i updated route to /users/{id} still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change id 'update-password' to 'update_password'

Ids should not contain dash(-)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing this endpoint :

```
/users/" + $('#update-password').attr("value")
```

But there is no `$id` as a url parameter in this endpoint, so you don't retrieve your `User`

What could work to get the current logged in users details is:

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

Auth class will return you the current logged in user details

Comment: i am trying to update password as admin of another user, i am getting that id from select. that's why i am passing id in controller.

Comment: So if you `dd($user)` the user results appears correctly?

Comment: Then the problem is not in there but in your previous class. Show us your full code.

Comment: i added view in question please check.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this

```
$('#update-password').val()
```

make sure that id "update-password" place in your input type["password"]

hope answer your question